# Counting table rows returns 1 row when the table is empty

Tags: mysql, yii2

I want to count the rows where id is let's say 32 with this command:

```
$countReviews = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                              FROM `product_review`
                                              WHERE `product_review`.`product_id`=$book->id")->execute();
```

There is no rows in the table but this returns 1 as result. Why is that ? Is this the right way to do the task?Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it returns 1 or some other value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns one row.  The *value* of the count is zero, but the number of rows is 1.

I think you are looking at the number of rows returned by the query, not at the value returned by the count.

Comment: Yes! Made another test and i saw the result which is 0. The array has one result which contains that 0 so i was realy looking at the length of the array i guess.

Answer (score 2):

`execute()` is for sql queries manipulating data (insert/update/delete etc).  As [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#execute()-detail) says:

> This method should only be used for executing **non-query** SQL statement, such as INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE SQLs. **No result set** will be returned.

You should use `query()` here, or even `querySacalar()` as you're expecting one single integer value.

Comment: Thank you! I have to read the documentation one more time i guess.